# rsync stuck with the --checksum option

Tags: linux, rsync

I use back-in-time to backup my Linux installation. It serves as an advanced wrapper for the `rsync` command.

Today I tried to add /var/log to the list of folders to be backed up and it caused some serious performance problems. The job seems to stuck on a particular file and the CPU usage of the `rsync` parent process reaches 100%. I then used `lsof` to see which file caused the problem and it seems to be the `/var/log` directory.

I did some googling and some experiments with the different `rsync` options and found `--checksum` to be the offender. Without the parameter, an incremental backup finishes properly in minutes. With it, the process will stuck when `rsync` tries to sync a constantly changing log file. This kind of make sense, but it still seems to be a bug to me.

Am I using the option correctly? Is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might consider performing a log rotation before the sync. Skip the active files, and just backup the archives. You could even make the rsync an postrotate action after the logs are normally rotated.

Comment: Yeah, I've been trying to do that, but back-in-time only allow me to change a small set of options. I can't specify the minimum modification age, so I may need to manually build an exclusion list which doesn't seem to be a robust method.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that the checksum is only there to verify that the file transfer has completed successfully.. a means to ensure the file is not corrupt if you will.

This may not be the answer you're looking for but --checksum is going to be slow. There is no way around it. If I were you I would create a quick bash script to compress all of your logs before you run the backup.

Something quick would suffice:

```
#!/bin/sh
for file in /path/to/log/dir/*;
do;
zip `basename $file`.zip *;
rm -f "$file";
done;
```

Then run your backup. This would save rsync from creating checksums of possibly huge log files anyway.

Be nice... I know it's not the answer you were looking for.

Good luck